# drop down value for hiding the columns share point is not working properly , but it works when value is selected one by one in different sessions

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I used below code in share point 2013 for hiding the columns based on a value in a form. I have 3 conditions here but when i select one value it hides the columns , but in the same session if i select another value it will not hide the columns as expected instead it shows one or two columns. But when i select one value in one session it hides the columns and submit the form. can any one help me on below.

```
<script src="/business/49898/Request%20form%20library/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="/business/49898/Request%20form%20library/sputility.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).change(function() 
    {  


        var studentType = SPUtility.GetSPField('Request Form Type');  


        var showOrHideField = function() {  
            var studentTypeValue = studentType.GetValue();  




              if (studentTypeValue == 'Tracking Number request') {  
                SPUtility.HideSPField('CSB Site Long Title');
    SPUtility.HideSPField('Opportunity Type');
    SPUtility.HideSPField('Sales Stage');
    SPUtility.HideSPField('Est. Close Date');
    SPUtility.HideSPField('Proposal Submission Date');

            }   

       if (studentTypeValue == 'Open project in PCB request') {  
                SPUtility.HideSPField('Secondary Unit Sales Rep/Business Unit name');
                SPUtility.HideSPField('Start Opportunity');
                SPUtility.HideSPField('Proposal Submission Date');
                SPUtility.HideSPField('Est. Close Date');
                SPUtility.HideSPField('Sales Stage');
                SPUtility.HideSPField('Opportunity Type');                 
            }

        if (studentTypeValue == 'Add or Update CGI CRM Sales Funnel request')
            {  
             SPUtility.HideSPField('Title');
    SPUtility.HideSPField('Engagement Type');
    SPUtility.HideSPField('Account Manager');
    SPUtility.HideSPField('VP Consulting Srvc');
    SPUtility.HideSPField('Sale Representative/Opportunity Manager');
    SPUtility.HideSPField('Network and Activity (NWA)');
    SPUtility.HideSPField('CPMF Tracking Number');


            } 
       };  

        // run at startup (for edit form)  
        showOrHideField();  

        // make sure if the user changes the value we handle it  
        $(studentType.Dropdown).on('change', showOrHideField);  


    });
    </script> 
<p> ​</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have hide logic, you need show the hided fields when option changes.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="/siteassets/sputility.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var studentType = SPUtility.GetSPField('Request Form Type');
            var showOrHideField = function () {
                var studentTypeValue = studentType.GetValue();
                if (studentTypeValue == 'Tracking Number request') {
                    //SPUtility.HideSPField('CSB Site Long Title');
                    SPUtility.HideSPField('Opportunity Type');
                    //SPUtility.HideSPField('Sales Stage');
                    //SPUtility.HideSPField('Est. Close Date');
                    //SPUtility.HideSPField('Proposal Submission Date');
                    SPUtility.ShowSPField('Start Opportunity');
                    SPUtility.ShowSPField('Account Manager');
                }

                if (studentTypeValue == 'Open project in PCB request') {
                    //SPUtility.HideSPField('Secondary Unit Sales Rep/Business Unit name');
                    SPUtility.HideSPField('Start Opportunity');
                    //SPUtility.HideSPField('Proposal Submission Date');
                    //SPUtility.HideSPField('Est. Close Date');
                    //SPUtility.HideSPField('Sales Stage');
                    //SPUtility.HideSPField('Opportunity Type');
                    SPUtility.ShowSPField('Opportunity Type');
                    SPUtility.ShowSPField('Account Manager');
                }

                if (studentTypeValue == 'Add or Update CGI CRM Sales Funnel request') {
                    //SPUtility.HideSPField('Title');
                    //SPUtility.HideSPField('Engagement Type');
                    SPUtility.HideSPField('Account Manager');
                    //SPUtility.HideSPField('VP Consulting Srvc');
                    //SPUtility.HideSPField('Sale Representative/Opportunity Manager');
                    //SPUtility.HideSPField('Network and Activity (NWA)');
                    //SPUtility.HideSPField('CPMF Tracking Number');
                    SPUtility.ShowSPField('Opportunity Type');
                    SPUtility.ShowSPField('Start Opportunity');
                }
            };

            // run at startup (for edit form)
            showOrHideField();
            // make sure if the user changes the value we handle it
            $(studentType.Dropdown).on('change', showOrHideField);
        });
    </script>
```